# How to change Laravel model's table name

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am using Laravel 5 and have changed the name of a database table from  "domain_related_settings" to "DomainRelatedSettings" by rolling back all migrations, changing the specific migration, and running them again. The new table name is reflected in the database.

But when i use the corresponding model `DomainRelatedSetting` in a statement like this:

```php
$domainSettings = DomainRelatedSetting::where('hostname', 'foo')->first();
```

it gives the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found:
1146 Table 'databasename.domain_related_settings' doesn't exist
(SQL: select * from `domain_related_settings` where `hostname` = foo limit 1)
```

So it is still using the old table name. How can I ensure the new table name is used?

Comment: after defining table property on model class `protected $table = 'DomainRelatedSettings';` it still giving the error?

Comment: no, when i add this row the error is gone.

Comment: Check the `Table Names` section: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#defining-models

Comment: I thought i should use the singular form in my model and the plural form in the table. But it seems that when my model is name "SomeExample". It not only looks for the plural version but also for "some_example". Thanks. Sometimes i don't understand why they don't add a more a more comprehensive example in the (already very good) docs.

Answer (score 89):

If you don't want to use the default `table` name (*the "snake case", plural name of the class*), you should specify it to the `model`:

```
protected $table = 'DomainRelatedSettings';
```

Check the documentation at the [`Table Names`](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#defining-models) section.

Answer (score 47):

You may specify a custom table by defining a table property on your model:

```
class theModel extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'name_of_table';
}
```

In case it doesn't work, try typing this command inside from your root folder:

`composer dump-autoload -o`

Answer (score 24):

You need to specify the table name inside the each Laravel model by using

```
protected $table = 'name_of_table';
```

so in your case

```
protected $table = 'DomainRelatedSettings';
```

Answer (score 3):

If you specify the real name of the tables in your models but still the same problem, try:

```
composer dump-autoload
```